# Understanding factorials in Python

Tags: python

I know how to code a function for the factorial of a number but I am not sure why it works.

```
def factorial (num):
    ans = 1
    for i in range (1,num + 1):
        ans *= i
    return (ans)
```

In my mind ans remains one and is multiplied by every index on 1 through nums + 1. So it would look like: (1 * 1, 1 * 2, 1 * 3,...). How does this function lead to the factorial of the number in the parameter?

Comment: `ans` can't remain 1 since you write to it with `ans *= i`

Comment: There is nothing in this code that creates a sequence. If you want to understand it better, put `print(i, ans)` inside the loop to see their values.

Comment: `a *= b` means : take the content of `a`, multiply it by `b`, and **store the result into a again**. So there is one variable (`a` in my example is `ans` for you) that takes the role of growing until the big final result. By the way, sometimes we call this kind of variable an "accumulator", in algorithmics.

Answer (score 4):

Why not introduce some print statements in your code to see what is going on?

```
def factorial(num):
    ans = 1
    for i in range(1, num + 1):
        print(f" ans = {ans}, going to multiply by {i}")
        ans *= i
    return ans


print("Trying to find the factorial of 5")
final = factorial(5)
print(f"Final answer is: {final}")
```

This gives:

```
Trying to find the factorial of 5
 ans = 1, going to multiply by 1
 ans = 1, going to multiply by 2
 ans = 2, going to multiply by 3
 ans = 6, going to multiply by 4
 ans = 24, going to multiply by 5
Final answer is: 120
```

So bottom line, you need to better understand what `*=` is doing in `ans *= i` (aka in-place operators), see here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#in-place-operators

Answer (score 1):

`a *= b` means :

1. take the content of `a`,
2. multiply it by `b`,
3. and store the result into `a` again.

(`a` in my example is `ans` for you)

So there is one variable, the same is used for every iteration. There is no list or such as you think it does, that takes the role of growing until the big final result.

`ans` starts at the value of 1, then will be multiplied by 2, and the result will replace it so it becomes `2`, then will be multiply by 3, so it becomes 1 * 2 * 3 = `6`, etc..

By the way, sometimes we call this kind of variable an "accumulator", in algorithmics.

Answer (score 0):

Note the usage of the `*=` operator - in each iteration of the loop `ans` is multiplied by `i`, and the result saved back to `ans`.

Let's look at the first couple of iterations:

1. `i=1` - `ans` * `i` is 1*1, or 1, which is saved back in `ans`.
2. `i=2` - `ans` * `i` is 1*2, or 2, which is saved back in `ans`.
3. `i=3` - `ans` * `i` is 2*3, or 6, which is saved back in `ans`.
   ... and so on.